# jquery drag and drop boxes with callback

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I'm looking for a solution similar to [this](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#photo-manager).

I want to move max 6 from 20 modules to the Trash box.

When Trash is full I need to display additional message: '*trash is full*'.

When I move 1 element - I need to display a message like '*you dropped A-module*' in the trash.

Could you please give me a hand in it?

Comment: You should read the API documentation and attempt it first: http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/ & http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [JQFAQ](http://jqfaq.com/how-to-know-when-an-item-is-dropped-and-how-to-prevent-dropping/) topic, it will help you to do this.